# IFormCollection not receiving single form data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, forms

I am working on asp.net core MVC project. There is a view that already have a form with some static fields that are submitted to the backend and data is saved in DB. Now there is a requirement to add dynamic fields in the view. These fields will be coming from the DB. After rendering these fields, there comes the part to submit the data for these dynamic fields. What I understand is you can use FormCollections to gather form fields inside a form. So what I did is create two forms, one with static and other with dynamic fields like below:

```
@model FormDataVM
<section>
    <form class="staticFormFields">
        <input type="text" id="FirstName" value="@Model.FirstName">
    </form>
    <form class="dynamicFormFields">
        @foreach (var field in Model.DynamicFields)
        {
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">@field.FieldTitle</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="@field.FieldType" placeholder="@field.FieldTitle" value="@field.FieldValue" name="@field.FieldCode" />
            </div>
        </div>
        }   
    </form>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SubmitForm">Save</button>

</section>
```

So at server side, I added an IFormCollection member in my viewmodel like this:

```
public class FormDataVM
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public IFormCollection DynamicFormFields { get; set; }
}
```

Then on button click, I send an Ajax call to the API like mentioned below:

```
<script>
function SubmitForm() {
    var firstName = $('#FirstName').val();
    var dynamicFormFields = $('#dynamicFormFields').serialize();;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: <API URL>,
                data: {
                    FirstName: ,
                    DynamicFormFields: dynamicFormFields
                },
                dataType: "json",   
            }).done(function (result) {
                if (!result.status) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
                alert("Success");
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I was hoping for was the DynamicFormFields will only contain the fields in dynamic form but it contains the list of all the fields i.e. fields in both staticForm and dynamicForm. When I debugged my ajax call, the object dynamicFormFields do contain only dynamic fields but when the call reaches the server side, DynamicFormFields variable contains all the fields data. I am clearly missing something here. Can anyone please guide me why is this happening and what would be the proper way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might face such issue, I was not able to resolve this issue but decided take another approach. I changed my variable(DynamicFormFields) type from IFormCollection to string and from client side, I am sending JSON string.

JavsScript code looks something like this:

```
<script>
function SubmitForm() {
    var firstName = $('#FirstName').val();
    var dynamicFormFields = JSON.stringify($('#dynamicFormFields').serializeArray());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: <API URL>,
        data: {
            FirstName: firstName,
            DynamicFormFields: dynamicFormFields
        },
        dataType: "json",   
    }).done(function (result) {
        if (!result.status) {
            alert("Error");
        }
        alert("Success");
    });
}
</script>
```

And on server side, I am parsing this JSON as KeyValue pair like this:

```
var dynamicFieldList = JsonConvert.
                       DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DynamicFormKV>>
                       (FormDataVM.DynamicFormFields);
```

.

```
/** KV model for parsing dynamic form fields JSON **/

public class DynamicFormKV
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

/******/
```